# how to identify the points below a line in a graph using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, matlab-figure

After running the program, I got 14 values of `loglik`, then I plotted these value within two lines. The code is below:

```
loglik=[-3168.7176,-4644.451,-3759.7372,-1758.1307,-4813.0647,-4147.0188,...
        -4330.944,-4612.9895,-3829.8987,-2687.4927,...
        -4007.5629,-2799.527,-2747.96,4.386];
aH = axes;
plot(aH,loglik,'r.'); hold on;
threshold1=mean(loglik)+1*std(loglik);
threshold2=mean(loglik)+3*std(loglik);
plot(aH, aH.XLim, [threshold2, threshold2], 'r-');
plot(aH, aH.XLim, [threshold1, threshold1], 'r-');
```

Now, I want to identify the points which are below `threshold1`. How can I do that?

Comment: `loglik(loglik<threshold1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will distinguish visually between the points above\below `threshhold1`:

```
plot(aH,loglik(loglik>=threshold1),'r.');
hold on;
plot(aH,loglik(loglik<threshold1),'b.');
```

Points above (or equal to) `threshhold1` are red, and below are blue.

[image: threshhold]