# Matlab Plotting: if vector value >1, plot red, otherwise, plot blue

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Say I have a vector

```
X= [ 0.5, 2.1, 1
     0.2, -1, -1
     -0.2, 2, 1 ]
```

Like this.

normally, to plot in 2d plane, i can do:

`plot (X(:,1), X(:,2))`.

**Question: How do I plot, if element in X(:, 3)  is 1, plot red, if it's -1, plot blue?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to identify the points below a line in a graph using MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178320/how-to-identify-the-points-below-a-line-in-a-graph-using-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is (as usually...) matrix indexing: compare the third column of `X` to `+1` and `-1`, and select only these elements from `X`:

```
>> X(:,3) == 1
ans =
     1
     0
     1

>> X(X(:,3)==1,:)
ans =
    0.5000    2.1000    1.0000
   -0.2000    2.0000    1.0000
```

so, plotting is as simple as

```
plot( X(X(:,3)==+1,1), X(X(:,3)==+1,2), 'r*', ...
      X(X(:,3)==-1,1), X(X(:,3)==-1,2), 'b*')
```